# json parsing - Get values only under conditions

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to parse this JSON file to get some specific values.
What I want to achieve is to get "generator" and "payload" values. The tricky thing is that some items contain two results and some generators have two items too. In that case, I am only interested on payload value of the one with metadata info.

Desired output:

```
agentinfo, 3p95ouql5QgiZ2M7MBBQH5
log-audit, dWdVpfCCm44ax4KCyTEmhL
config, 1gi1QRjxme267adKl7Kqzn
```

I managed to get generator and results with `jq  '.audits[] | .generator, .results[].payload' manifest.json`, but the output is not exactly what I expect. Also tried `select` and `unique_by` but I didn't manage to get what I want.

```
{
    "type": "audit_manifest",
    "version": "1.0",
    "audits": [

        {
            "id": "",
            "generator": "agentinfo",
            "generatorVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "results": [
                {
                    "payload": "3p95ouql5QgiZ2M7MBBQH5",
                    "type": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "generator": "log-audit",
            "generatorVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "results": [
                {
                    "payload": "m3q1IVhgNk59VySdnvEXgk",
                    "type": "application/json"
                },
                {
                    "payload": "dWdVpfCCm44ax4KCyTEmhL",
                    "type": "application/octet-stream",
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "name",
                            "value": "agent.log"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "generator": "log-audit",
            "generatorVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "results": [
                {
                    "payload": "80iINCJwFFjcLp3BUf9Tec",
                    "type": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "generator": "config",
            "generatorVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "results": [
                {
                    "payload": "hRUiHto5JpcjnbD3tJQMx1",
                    "type": "application/json"
                },
                {
                    "payload": "1gi1QRjxme267adKl7Kqzn",
                    "type": "application/octet-stream",
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "name",
                            "value": "config.json"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "generator": "config",
            "generatorVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "results": [
                {
                    "payload": "SGf26By1b174bCLD0YYx01",
                    "type": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As always, thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq -r '
  reduce(.audits[] | {generator} * .results[]) as $item ({}; 
    (.[$item.generator]?) as $left
    | . * {($item.generator):
             (if ($left | has("metadata"))
              then $left else $item end) })
  | .[]
  | "\(.generator),\(.payload)"'
```

Output:

```
agentinfo,3p95ouql5QgiZ2M7MBBQH5
log-audit,dWdVpfCCm44ax4KCyTEmhL
config,1gi1QRjxme267adKl7Kqzn
```

Breaking that down a bit:

- `.audits[] | {generator} * .results[]` produces a flat list of "results" objects that know which generator produced them
- We `reduce` that list with the following logic. Reducing will start with the seed state (an empty object) and evaluate the expression with `.` set to the intermediate state and `$item` to an element of the flattened list. The output of the expression becomes the new intermediate state. At the end, the state is returned to the next step in the pipeline.

  - `(.[$item.generator]?) as $left`: we look up the generator in the intermediate state. If it is not yet there, this expression produces `null`
  - `. * {($item.generator): ...}`: we extend the intermediate state with an entry for `$item.generator`
  - `if ($left | has("metadata")) then $left else $item end`: we select the item that has a metadata key and otherwise select the incoming item. If this is the first time we see that key, `$left` is `null` and will not have a metadata key.
- `.[]`: get only the values from the resulting object
- `"\(.generator),\(.payload)"`: produce a nice string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward approach using `group_by`:

```
jq -r '
  [ .audits[]
    | .generator as $generator
    | .results
    | (map(select(.payload)) | length) as $npayloads
    | (if $npayloads == 1 then (.[] | select(.payload).payload)
       else first(.[] | select(.metadata).payload)
       end)  as $payload
    | {$generator, $payload} ]
  | group_by(.generator)
  | map(.[0])[]
  | "\(.generator),\(.payload)"
'
```

This produces the desired output, though you might wish to consider using `@csv` to be sure the output is valid as CSV.